# Create an instance within Abstract Class using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class

Is it possible to create an instance of a derived class in abstract ancestor class using reflection
Lets say:

```
abstract class Base {

public Base createInstance(){
  //using reflection
    Class<?> c = this.getClass();
    Constructor<?> ctor = c.getConstructor();
    return ((Base) ctor.newInstance());
}

}//end Base

class Derived extends Base {

 main(){

new Derived().createInstance()

 }
```

}

Comment: Did you try it? Seems like it would work.

Comment: What happened when you tried?  You can do this but its a fairly suspect design choice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It could be justified as a copy-method.

Comment: Note that you are wasting lines of code: `public Base createInstance() { return (Base) getClass().newInstance(); }` is all you need (module exceptions).

Comment: Umm. That code would not even compile at the first place. Anyways, what happened when you tried it?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println(new Derived().createInstance());
    }
}

abstract class Base {
    public Base createInstance() {
        //using reflection
        try {
            return getClass().asSubclass(Base.class).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Derived@55fe910c
```

A more common pattern is to use Cloneable

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    public static void main(String ... args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        System.out.println(new Derived().clone());
    }
}

abstract class Base implements Cloneable {
    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

prints

```
Derived@8071a97
```

However, the need to use either should be avoided.  Usually there is another way to do what you need so that base doesn't not implicitly depend on derived.

Answer (score 2):

Proving it works is easy:

```
abstract class Base {
  public Base createInstance() throws Exception {
    return getClass().newInstance();
  }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new Derived().createInstance().getClass());
  }
}
```

prints

```
class test.Derived
```

You should ask yourself twice why you need it and whether it is really a good approach for your problem. If you need cloning, consider the `clone` mechanism, which does basically the same thing.

Comment: I am trying to write an API(cover Base abstract class). And I need deepCopy method for this Base class.

Comment: Deep copying cannot be solved in the general, anyway. You'll need carefully thought-through custom code for each class. That's why you gain very little by generalizing instance creation code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.forName()` and `Class.newInstance()` to create any class. But there's no way to easily identify subclasses of a class. See [this JavaWorld tip](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip113.html) for a technique to do this.

I think , however, the real issue is what is it you're ultimately trying to achieve, and can it be done more easily using conventional techniques.