# How to call a constructor without warnings?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, warnings

I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507412/create-an-instance-within-abstract-class-using-reflection-with-constructor-param):

```
public Object loadService() throws Exception {
    ClassLoader parentClassLoader = ServiceReloader.class.getClassLoader();
    ServiceReloader classLoader = new ServiceReloader(parentClassLoader);
    Class aClass = classLoader.loadClass("pl.jcubic.Service");

    Constructor<?> ctor = aClass.getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
    return ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { cwd() });
}
```

(ServiceReloader is a class that extend ClassLoader that load a file pl/jcubic/Serice.class)
(My Service class how two constructors one with one argument String and one null one).

when I call that code I got:

```
init.java:40: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to getConstructor(Class<?>...) as a member of the raw type Class
        Constructor<?> ctor = aClass.getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
                                                   ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Class
1 warning
```

I'm not very familiar with generics, because when I learnt Java they were not included in the language.

I tried to put `Class<?>[]` but got the same warning. Is there a way to suppress this warning?

Comment: Why you are using arrays explicitly in `getConstructor` or `newInstance`? Varargs should let you use them as `getConstructor(String.class);` and `newInstance(cwd())`.

Comment: @Pshemo I found that in the other question in SO (the link is in the question), You can give beter answer to that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get rid of the warning, change to

```
Class<?> aClass = classLoader.loadClass("pl.jcubic.Service");
```

or

```
Constructor<?> ctor = ((Class<?>) aClass).getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
```

The issue is that `getConstructor`'s return type is `Constructor<T>` where `T` is the type parameter of the `Class` class. But since the compiler doesn't know the type argument for `aClass`, it will warn you.

Answer (score 0):

`getConstructor()` method is generic. If you want warning-free code add type parameter. For example the following line does not produce warning:

`Constructor<String> c = String.class.getConstructor();`

Since your method is generic add type parameter to the method definition:

```
public <T> T loadService() throws Exception {
    ............
    Constructor<T> c = clazz.getConstructor(params);
    T obj = c.newInstance(args);
    return obj;
}
```